# Custom User Edit Form not working with is valid method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

im new to django (doing my first project) and i can't figure out what goes wrong in my Custom User Edit Form.

```
class TestEditForm(ModelForm):
    old_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autofocus": True}))
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autofocus": True}))
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autofocus": True}))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "username", "old_password", "new_password1", "new_password2")

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super(TestEditForm, self).clean()
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        old_password = self.cleaned_data.get('old_password')
        new_password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
        new_password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')

        if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise ValidationError(u'Username "%s" is not available.' % username)

        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError(u'E-mail "%s" is not available.' % email)

        if not self.user.check_password(old_password):
            raise ValidationError('Incorrect password')

        if new_password1 and new_password2 and new_password1 != new_password2:
            raise ValidationError('Passwords do not match')

        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        new_password = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
        self.user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        self.user.username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        self.user.set_password(new_password)
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

CustomUser Model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_("username"), unique=True, max_length=30, validators=[username_validator],
                                error_messages={
                                    "unique": _("A user with that username already exists."),
                                }, )
    country = models.CharField(_("country"), max_length=40)
    liked_recipes = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe, default='', blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_("staff status"), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_("active"), default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_("date joined"), default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_country(self):
        return self.country

    def get_liked_recipes(self):
        return self.liked_recipes.all()
```

views.py:

```
def test(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestEditForm(request.POST)
        print('b4 valid')
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account successfully updated')
            return redirect('test')
        else:
            error_msg = form.errors
            messages.error(request, message=error_msg)

    form = TestEditForm(user=user, instance=user)
    context = {'user': user, 'form': form, 'sub_site_title': 'Edit account'}
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

It POSTS form but gets stuck on form.is_valid() and doesnt displays any errors

And html file:

```
<form name="form" autocomplete="off" class="ui form" action="" method="POST" id="edit">
    <div class="ui error message"></div>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="field">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <div class="ui input">{{ form.email }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Username</label>
        <div class="ui input">{{ form.username }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Current password</label>
        <div class="ui input">{{ form.old_password }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Password</label>
        <div class="ui input">{{ form.new_password1 }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Password confirmation</label>
        <div class="ui input">{{ form.new_password2 }}</div>
    </div>
        <div class="field">
        <input class="ui primary button" value="Update" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried using Form which inherited from PasswordChangeForm, UserChangeForm but it didnt work either

Comment: Can you include the validation errors please? You should be able to show them before is_valid by printing `form.errors`

Comment: _but gets stuck on form.is_valid() and doesnt displays any errors_ In order for the errors to be displayed, there needs to be a section in your html **that would display them**, and I don't see that.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to include that all messages are displayed in base template, which every sub view extends